# Forecasting sales during time of epidemic

Tags: time-series, predictive-modeling

As we are going through a tough time because of the Coronavirus epidemic, is it possible to somehow include this affect of this in predicting sales as a time-series for next few weeks?

I am new to time series forecasting but any idea will help here.